# C++ rvalue присваивание объекта

Tags: c++

Работаю с std::list
Есть класс TTimerData  (с методами) который надо поместить в лист

```
class TTimerData 
{
  public:
  float tick1_ON; 
  float tick2_OFF; 
  uint32_t time_on; 

  TTimerData(float ptick1_ON,   float ptick2_OFF, uint32_t ptime_on);
};
```

С этой целью пишу:

```
std::list<TTimerData> lst;
TTimerData * a=new TTimerData(0,0,11);
lst.push_back(a);
```

Компилятор на меня злобно ругается и говорит что я передал неверный тип.

```
lst.push_back(TTimerData(0,0,11));
```

На такую запись компилятор не ругается - но при этом создается временный объект в стеке. При удалении TTimerData из list должен сработать деструктор и должно вызваться освобождение памяти - что наверно может привести к ошибке.

В заголовке метод push_back определен так:
"При подстановке value_type = TTimerData"

```
 void push_back(const value_type& __x)
 void  push_back(value_type&& __x)
```

Вопрос:
  Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно в метод push_back передать значение 
new TTimerData(0,0,11) ?
  Или можно все таки использовать временный объект в стеке?

Comment: У вас в списке хранятся *копии* исходных объектов. Им глубоко все равно, где располагался исходный объект, который вы передавали в `push_back`. Для списка нет никакой разницы, было ли у вас там `new` или не было.

Comment: дело в том, что вы хотели в список обьектов запихнуть указатель на обьект. Правильно:  lst.push_back(*a);

Comment: Вы случаем не с джавы какой-нибудь пересаживаетесь? В С++ совершенно другая семантика ссылок и значений. А правильно будет сделать `lst.emplace_back(0, 0, 11);`

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, а кто потом утечку памяти будет фиксить?

Comment: @VTT, ответы - в ответы.

Answer (score 0):

В библиотеке list (версия для arduino) метод push_back определен следующим образом:

```
void push_back(const value_type& __x)
void  push_back(value_type&& __x)
```

Для определения метода:

```
void push_back(const value_type& __x)
```

подходит следующий вызов:

```
   TTimerData * a = new TTimerData(0,0,11);
   lst.push_back(*a);
   lst.push_back( *(new TTimerData(0,0,11)));
```

Для определения метода:

```
void  push_back(value_type&& __x)
```

Применяется вызов:

```
lst.push_back(TTimerData(0,0,11));
```

Вот тут:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535223/why-cant-i-push-this-object-onto-my-stdlist
Matt написал:

Обратите внимание, что TTimerData будет скопирован в ваш список; неявно сгенерированный конструктор копирования TTimerData (поскольку вы не объявили конструктор TTimerData (const TTimerData и др.) в своем классе, компилятор сделал это за вас) скопирует TTimerData.tick1_ON и TTimerData.tick2_OFF в список.
 В этом случае это нормально. Размер TTimerData мал, поэтому затраты на копирование невелики и содержат только три целых числа, так что копирование целых значений в порядке.